# How to use Edittext in multiple other activities

Tags: android

I have an edittext where you can enter your name, so the name can be used in new activities. But i get an error when I go to the next page.

The code of the activity with the edittext:

```
 public class aanmeldbalie extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText SendValue;
    Button SendEditTextValue;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aanmeldbalie);

        SendEditTextValue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAanmeldbalie);
        SendValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kandidaatsnaam);

        SendEditTextValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),wachtkamer.class);
                intent.putExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE", SendValue.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent wachtkamer = new Intent(this, wachtkamer.class);
        startActivity(wachtkamer);
    }
```

The code of the activity where we want to use the edittext:

```
    TextView receive;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dokter);

        receive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.kandidaatsnaam);

        receive.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE"));
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent uitleg_zuster = new Intent(this, uitleg_zuster.class);
        startActivity(uitleg_zuster);
    }
```

The XML-code of the edittext:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Naam"
    android:layout_below="@id/tekstvak1"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:background="#B3FFFFFF"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/kandidaatsnaam"
    />
```

Comment: use SharedPreference for get value anytime anywhere in Application

Comment: Must sure that  you'r not starting activity twice for single button from xml and from java file too

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: If you are using "android:onClick:sendMessage", then why are you using click listener over button, your sendMessage()  method is called, where you are not passing anything in intent, hence you getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the below code:-

**

    SendEditTextValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),wachtkamer.class);
                intent.putExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE", SendValue.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

**
And add the below make sendMessage() like this:


public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent uitleg_zuster = new Intent(this, uitleg_zuster.class);
intent.putExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE", SendValue.getText().toString());
    startActivity(uitleg_zuster);
}

Make sure u have android:onClick="sendMessage" in xml file

<Button
  android:text="send"
  android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the onclick like this and No need of the send Message Function.

```
SendEditTextValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent = new Intent(aanmeldbalie.this,wachtkamer.class);
            intent.putExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE", SendValue.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

And in your second Activity

```
receive.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("EdiTtEXTvALUE"));
```

Put this piece of code inside try catch or check for null value to prevent from null pointer Exception.